# icepush-basic example does nothing

Tags: java, tomcat, icepush

I'm new to icepush.

I have started icepush-basic example under Tomcat 6. I made WAR file with Ant and deployed it as apropriate.

I see the page "Basic ICEpush Test Current Push Notifications: " and nothing more hapenning.

Then I ran this sample under eclipse debugger and see, that timers on the server-side work well, i.e. pushing something into bridge.

Also I see in firebug, that my browser is querying listen.icepush URL periodically with correct pushids in POST data.

But the response of the query is always

```
<noop/>
```

and the registered function never called.

What can be the reason of this?

icechat-ajax example works well in the same circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in icepush library: individual sendings, which are used in an example, do not implemented.